# newline character within script tags

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am learning servlets and I tried creating this basic calculator. I was trying to add all exceptions to a string and printing that string on the web page as an error msg. I am including only the essential parts of the code

```
public class Calculator extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String x = request.getParameter("x");
        String y = request.getParameter("y");
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        String errorMsg = "";
                if (x != null && y == null) {
            errorMsg = errorMsg.concat("Y cannot be blank\n");
        }
        else if (x == null && y != null) {
            errorMsg = errorMsg.concat("X cannot be blank");
        }
                out.println("<!doctype html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Calculator</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        if (!errorMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            out.println("<h2>"+errorMsg+"</h2>");
        }

        out.println("<form>");
        out.println("<table border='1' style='background-color:#999'>");
        out.println("<tr><td>X </td> <td><input type='text' id='xValue' name='x' /></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td>Y </td> <td><input type='text' id='yValue' name='y' /></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td colspan='2'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' id='plusButton' value='+' name='add' />");
        out.println("<input type='submit' id='minusButton' value='-' name='sub' />");
        out.println("<input type='submit' id='mulButton' value='*' name='mul' />");
        out.println("<input type='submit' id='divButton' value='/' name='div' />");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</form></body></html>");

    }
}
```

If I input letters into the X and Y textfields I should get an error msg. More specifically I should get two error msgs on two separate lines. However I am getting both of them on the same line. On the command line I am getting them on different lines. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Good and clear question, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new line characters (`\n` `\r` or both) are not rendered as a new line in HTML.

In order to see new lines in HTML you need to use a designated line break tag

```
<br>
```

e.g.

```
    String errorMsg = "";
    if (x != null && y == null) {
        errorMsg = errorMsg.concat("Y cannot be blank<br>");
    }
    else if (x == null && y != null) {
        errorMsg = errorMsg.concat("X cannot be blank");
    }
```